# Turn off suggestions bar for Chrome in Android phone

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, google-chrome

I am looking to turn off spelling suggestions for a input box and I am not able to achieve it.

I used autocomplete="off" , autocapitalize="off" and spellcheck="off" for the input but am able to see the bar above keypad showing suggestions.

This is affecting my layout. Looking for working solutions.

Comment: Your title says “spellcheck”, your question body says “suggestions”. Which one do you mean? Also please include the relevant HTML and CSS (and say how CSS is relevant here). And do you seriously mean that you want to disable an essential usability feature to protect your layout?

Comment: Yes I am serious. I am trying to solve a layout issue in many ways. One among those is to disable this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Cordova for this, in html5 there is the spellcheck attribute.

```
<input type="text" spellcheck="false">
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to be clear about the input box, is it an edit text? if yes using the following in your xml could help :

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

Comment: How can I do this textNoSuggestions through javascript?

Comment: the general solution for that in javascript is using the autocomplete="off" but since its not working for you, you need to show the code so we can know where the problem is rising from

Answer (score 0):

For html input , you can use `autocorrect` attribute

```
<input autocorrect="off"/>
```

For native android xml `EditText`, you can specify `inputType`

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"/>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I used autocomplete="off" , autocapitalize="off" and spellcheck="off" but if did not work. No mine is not a native application

Comment: Try `autocorrect="off"`. That is for suggestion bar. @RavitejaAvvari

Comment: That's exactly what I used for my input and still I am able to see the suggestions bar.

Answer (score 0):

The answer here is that you can't turn it off on Droid Chrome.  If you use (autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off") then this will stop auto completion (picking words from the bar automatically).  If you want to turn off the suggestions bar completely, this only works on iPhone.  So to turn off that, you can use (autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck={false}) - this still works on Droid but I can't turn the address bar off.  Having words get auto replaced, when the dictionary match with the field inputs are weak, is not a good idea. Although you can only disable this lookup bar on iPhone - it gets you 12% extra space to see stuff on a 6.1" iPhone and on a 5.4" iPhone (12 mini) it will get you a whopping 15% extra space when the keyboard is up.